# Asymptotic series in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, perturbation-theory, asymptotics

In QFT is said that the renormalized Dyson series is only asymptotic. But to be able to say it is necessary to know to what function of $g$ (the coupling constant) the Dyson series is asymptotic.

For example, suppose that some transition amplitude $A(g)$ is given perturbatively by a series of powers of $g$. In order to prove that this series is asymptotic to $A(g)$ I need to know the value of $A(g)$ non-perturbatively, but this is not possible since the only way $A(g)$ is given is the Dyson series.

Comment: There are some cases where $A(g)$ is known non-perturbatively, in which case it can be proven that the series is indeed asymptotic. In the rest of cases, one assumes that there is no miracle that comes to the rescue -- although this is definitely no proof.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Any examples where $A(g)$ is known?

Comment: @JamalS e.g., zero dimensional QFT's; Thirring/Sine-Gordon; the effective action for constant electromagnetic field (cf. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/359640/84967));some super-symmetric results (?);...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: You forgot scalar $\phi^4$ models in 2d and 3d.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $A(g)$ is given by some perturbative expansion around $g=0$:
$$A(g) = \sum_n c_n g^n.$$
Then the statement that this expansion is asymptotic means that the radius of convergence is zero: for fixed $g$, no matter how small, the limit
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \; \sum_{n < N} c_n g^n$$
diverges. Typically it's enough to know that large-$n$ behaviour of the coefficients $c_n$ to establish this. In QFT, sometimes you can estimate the magnitude of the $c_n$ (e.g. you count the number of Feynman diagrams at $n$-loop order multiplied by the typical contribution of a single diagram). For instance, if
$$c_n  \sim  n!$$
you can prove that the series is asymptotic. You do this using the tools you learned in undergrad calculus (for example the ratio test).

Notice that this is a really fast growing series: if for instance $c_n \sim a^n$ for some constant $a$, then you have convergence inside a disk $|g| \leq 1/a$. So you need even faster than exponential growth of the $c_n$ to have an asymptotic series.

Comment: There’s also an interesting and unexpected fact: the same asymptotic expansion can approximate two different functions. In QFT, this corresponds to the possibility of having inequivalent nonperturbative theories agreeing with the same perturbation theory.

Answer (score 5):

By the [Borel-Ritt Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Borel_theorem), any (formal) power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n g^n$ is the asymptotic expansion at zero of some $C^{\infty}$ function $A(g)$. Of course the latter is very non-unique. You raised a good point about what is this $A(g)$ that the series should be asymptotic *to*? or since we know the existence of $A(g)$, the question should rather be what is the *right* $A(g)$? i.e. one needs some uniqueness, via imposing some extra conditions. It is known that for scalar fields in 2d and 3d ($\phi^4$ model) the perturbative series has zero radius of convergence but is also asymptotic to a non-perturbative definition of $A(g)$ obtained via the hard estimates of constructive quantum field theory. Moreover, the non-perturbative $A(g)$ is the Borel sum of the (moderately) renormalized perturbative series. This is one way of restoring uniqueness.
The two references on this are

1. Eckmann, Magnen, Sénéor, ["Decay properties and Borel summability for the Schwinger functions in $P(\Phi)_2$ theories"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01705374?LI=true), CMP 1975.
2. Magnen, Sénéor, ["Phase space cell expansion and borel summability for the Euclidean $\varphi_{3}^{4}$ theory"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01614211?LI=true), CMP 1977.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: it's pretty clear from the context but I added the word "formal" anyway.

Comment: Sure, it's clear, but hey, it won't hurt to be  precise (although admittedly slightly pedantic). Not everyone knows as much as you; a single word may help.

Comment: Tank you so much for the  informations. Are there non-perturbative estimates even for more realistic QFT such as  QED and QCD ?

Comment: I would Have another problem related to the previous one : I don't understand why going to high perturbative orders ( high pwers of g )it also goes towards  great virtual energies ( Folland  " QFT a tourist guide for mathematicians " pag. 253 : "...high order Feynman diagrams in QED describe electromagnetic processes involving large number of virtual particles and hence large virtual energies ... ". Even a feynman diagram with  only one loop implies arbitrarily large energies with respect to the virtual particle.

Comment: @SergioDenti: "more realistic" implies that $\phi^4$ type scalar models are not realistic which is a rather misleading statement. Since 2012 we know there is particle in nature described by a scalar field. For QED in 3d see this article by Dimock and references therein https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04373 for Yang-Mills in 4d with group SU(2) see this article https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104253284 and cited work of Balaban therein. Presumably the same methods should work for SU(3), i.e., QCD.