# Exotic perturbative anomaly captured only by higher-loop Feynman graphs, but not by any 1-loop Feynman graph?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-anomalies

> My question: Are there any perturbative anomaly captured by higher-loop but not by  captured at the 1-loop Feynman graph (say, not enough)?

We are familiar with the text book example of a perturbative anomaly captured by 1-loop Feynman graph, such as the ABJ anomaly.

[image]

All anomalies in Green-Schwarz mechanism are also perturbative anomaly captured by 1-loop Feynman graphs. I also know global anomalies of Witten SU(2) and global gravitational anomalies not captured by perturbative Feynman graphs.

My question: Are there any perturbative anomaly captured by higher-loop but not by  captured at the 1-loop Feynman graph (say, not enough)?

Comment: In a large class of theories, the [Adler-Bardeen theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6453), which states that if anomalies vanish at one loop, then they vanish to all orders, has been proved to hold.

Comment: possible dup.? [When is an anomaly one-loop exact?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436410/84967).

Comment: I am asking beyond 1-loop, thus it is not a duplicated question -- please do not limit the imagination.